# FTP server with http based administration gui for Linux

Tags: linux, server, ftp

I want a FTP server that can be controlled over a web GUI. I mean not upload/download files, but administrate the server - creating users, administrate them (passwords, directories, quotas, etc). Dedicated (not like webmin) web-based solution would be preferred.

Comment: By "Dedicated", do you mean SaaS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another web frontend for [ProFTPd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProFTPD) that is often used: [Webmin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ProFTPD_Server) (open source, gratis, BSD-like license).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Webmin is nice and up to date. But it's not dedicated solution. AFAIK there are no chance to grant webmin access to somebody to control ftp only or not?

Comment: I don't think so but unsure.

Comment: At the moment the best solution is virtual win xp and any server for windows... Easy movable, easy configurable, dedicated...

Comment: @Yuri Yeah on Windows I use FileZilla Server.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [ProFTPd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProFTPD). It comes with all the stuff you want from your FTP Server. It does not come with a Web frontend but there are several GUIs that do connect to it.

I have used [GAdmin](http://freecode.com/projects/gadmin-proftpd) which is a desktop client. But there exists [PPMY](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ppmy/) just for user/group management and [ProFTPd Administrator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proftpd-adm/) which does serve more.

You will need to setup a MySQL for them to work, but that will most likely be done by your package system for you.